# How to activate script.disable_dynamic in spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

Can someone help me ?

I want to set `script.disable_dynamic` to `false` in `spring-data.elasticsearch`.

I'm using spring boot .

Comment: I don't know how to do it.           i try this config   in  my application.yml spring boot config      data:
        elasticsearch:
            cluster-name:
            cluster-nodes:
            properties:
                scripting.disabled: false
                path:
                  logs: target/elasticsearch/log
                  data: target/elasticsearch/data
                http:
                  enabled: true
                  port: 9200

Comment: And i 'm still getting this error :  nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; }]",

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guy , i find the solution.

For elasticsearch 1.5 and spring boot , i juste add this line to my spring configuration file application.yml
**script.disable_dynamic : false**  (not scripting.disabled: false)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES 1.6+, you can [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) by updating the following settings that need to be added to the `config/elasticsearch.yml` file on every node.

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
```